# Python SOAP client library using a HTTPS connection with keys

Tags: python, soap

I want to query a SOAP service that requires the use of keys.

I could write a SOAP client myself making use of httplib's HTTPSConnection, I'm pretty sure that would work, but it means I have to write a load of XML. Is there a nicer way to do this? Perhaps getting an existing SOAP library to use a HTTPSConnection object.

I found [an example](http://www.filewatcher.com/p/python-soappy_0.9.7-3.tar.gz.78630/python-soappy-0.9.7/README.html) from 2001 based on an old version of SOAPpy (not SOAPy) but I think the SOAPpy library has changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

See [`twisted.web.xmlrpc.Proxy`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.web.xmlrpc.Proxy.html). The `url` argument knows about `HTTPS`:

> `url` - The URL to which to post method calls. Calls will be made over SSL if the scheme is HTTPS.

This [`twisted` doc page](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/xmlrpc.html#auto4) claims

> From the point of view of a Twisted developer, there is little difference between XML-RPC support and SOAP support.

Following the example there, it should not be difficult to make `SOAP HTTPS` calls. Note that `twisted` tends to be different from other `Python` networking frameworks, and has a significant learning curve.

For `PKI HTTPS` support, see [validate-ssl-certificates-with-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087227/validate-ssl-certificates-with-python). It looks like there are some limitations, hopefully the `Twisted API` will cater to your needs.

Comment: I can't see a way to specify keys unfortunately.

Comment: Added ref to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087227/validate-ssl-certificates-with-python