# Drop-in replacement for `urllib2.urlopen` that does cert verification

Tags: python, ssl, https, certificate

I use Python's `urllib2.urlopen` for talking with HTTPS servers, but I now learned on the [documentation](http://025123522) that "HTTPS requests [using `urllib2.urlopen`] do not do any verification of the server’s certificate."

This is a big problem for me, because it leaves my servers open to a MITM attack.

I want a drop-in replacement for `urllib2.urlopen` that does cert-verification, so I could bundle it with my code and replace all calls to `urllib2.urlopen` with calls to the modified `urlopen` function.

Because this is a security issue, I much prefer battle-tested security-audited code rather than some random recipe from the internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate SSL certificates with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087227/validate-ssl-certificates-with-python)

Comment: The above linked-to question has a drop-in urllib2 component in one of the answers.

Comment: [`urllib2_ssl.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/1347055) allows you to enable cert verification for `urllib2.urlopen()`

Comment: Cert verification is performed from Python 2.7.9 / 3.4.3 on, by default. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/

Answer (score 2):

The situation changed, fortunately. Certificate verification is by default enabled from Python 2.7.9 / 3.4.3 on. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/ for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/. It uses libcurl which is certainly mature and well tested.

It isn't a "drop in" replacement though. The api is different.

**Edit** better still, look at the question linked to by @Sven in his comment (which also suggests pycurl as an option).

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [this library](http://code.google.com/p/python-httpclient/), although it's not a drop-in replacement. It uses `ssl` or `OpenSSL`, depending on the version of Python you're using, and `httplib`.

Comment: httpclient looks great. Definitely worth a look