# How can I get a Python SOAP client to use certificates correctly?

Tags: python, soap, client, certificate

I'm trying to access a server via SOAP with Python and I'm running into errors that tell me that I need to use the correct certificate - but I'm sure that I'm doing that.

I have some instructions that I'm following for going through this exercise - I need to connect over a WSDL link using HTTPS and invoke one Method on the server. I converted the key that I received, using OpenSLL, to key.pm and cert.pem; I also tried SUDS and some other workarounds. With everything I try, though, the service tells me that I need to use the correct certificate.

I know that the certificates are actually correct because I installed a SOAP client for Firefox and when I connect to the server using thesame certificates and the same arguments, I get valid data instead of the error message. Because of this, I think there's something wrong with how SUDS communicates about certificates. I tried the workarounds from a "[SUDS over HTTPS with cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277027/suds-over-https-with-cert)" question, but those aren't working for me.

Is there a way around this, or is there another Python SOAP client that works with certificates correctly (even if I have to manually create the XML for the request)?