# Porting perl soap application to python

Tags: python, perl, soap

I'm trying to port my Perl SOAP communication application to a Python equivalent at the moment but can't seem to get past this error that `urllib2` is throwing via `suds`. My working perl soap script is:

```
use myStub;
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_FILE} = '/path/to/certificate';
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_PASSWORD} = 'password';
my $client = new myStub;
my $output = $client->foo('test', 'something');
print $output
```

where `myStub` is the .pm created by `stubmaker.pl` as part of `SOAP::Lite`.

and I set up my python script as follows:

```
from suds.client import Client
import os

os.environ['HTTPS_PKCS12_FILE'] = '/path/to/certificate'
os.environ['HTTPS_PKCS12_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
client = Client('file:WSDL')
output = client.service.foo('test', 'something')
print output
```

which gives me:

```
File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    output = client.service.foo('test', 'something')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 643, in send
    reply = transport.send(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 64, in send
    return  HttpTransport.send(self, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 77, in send
    fp = self.u2open(u2request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 118, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1198, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1165, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:490: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
```

The `suds` client is getting created fine and if I print it out, I get the expected methods being listed etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like `urllib2` is unable to communicate with the server. I doubt `urllib2` is paying any attention to the `HTTPS_PKCS12_*` environment variables. My guess would be that those are specific to the Perl library you were using, or to Perl itself. `urllib2` doesn't do any SSL cert validation at all, if you want that you're better off using [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/).

These two questions might point you in the right direction:

- [Suds over https with cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277027/suds-over-https-with-cert)
- [Validate SSL certificates with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087227/validate-ssl-certificates-with-python)