# https handshake with keystores in Python

Tags: python, ssl, https, pkcs#12

I have an web server set up that denies connections without a valid .p12 certificate.  I need to access a REST API that is running on the server in a Python script, but I can't find anything about how to do it.  If anyone has a good tutorial on how to perform an SSL handshake using .p12 certificates in Python, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same methods described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1087227/372643), which asks about verifying a server certificate during the HTTPS connection (this is not done at all by default by `urllib` or `httplib`) should allow you to specify a client-certificate in addition to the CA certificate lists.

- If you choose the option based on [`ssl.wrap_socket`](http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html), pass a `cerfile`/`keyfile` parameter as described in the documentation.
- Using PycURL, you should be able to call `setopt(pycurl.SSLCERT, "/path/to/cert.pem")` and `setopt(pycurl.SSLKEY, "/path/to/key.pem")`. The option names are based on the [*SSL and SECURITY OPTIONS* section of the cURL documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) (there's an option for the password too).

It's likely that you will have to convert your PKCS#12 (`.p12`) file into PEM format. To do so:

```
# Extract the certificate:
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.p12 -nokeys -out certificate.pem

# Extract the private key:
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.p12 -nocerts -out privkey.pem
```