# ssl certificate authentication in python

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have been given the following code that should perform an ssl handshake and certificate authentication:

```
1   s = socket.socket()
2   print "connecting..."
3   logging.debug("Connecting")
4   # Connect with SSL mutual authentication
5   # We only trust our server's CA, and it only trusts user certificates signed by it
6   c = ssl.wrap_socket(s, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
7                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3, ca_certs='ca.crt',
8                       certfile='user.crt', keyfile='user.key')
9   c.connect((constants.server_addr, constants.port))
```

I have 2 questions about this:

1. where do we specify the server/port to which we are connecting?  are these arguments to `socket.socket()`?
2. I have a .p12 from which I extracted a cert and a key in pem format(see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504195/https-handshake-with-keystores-in-python/10508130#10508130)), and I assume that these correspond to `user.crt` and `user.key` (line 8), respectively.  However, while I assume that `ca.crt` (line 7) is retrived from the certificate authority, how to I retrieve it?

If any part of the above code or my assumptions about it are incorrect, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually -- PKCS#12 files (your `.p12` file) can, and typically _do_, contain the relevant CA certificate as well.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, your own PKCS#12 file is likely to contain your own certificate's chain, but not the servers (unless they are the same, which isn't necessarily the case).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how would I retrieve the CA cert from the p12?

Comment: @Bruno Fair enough -- I was presuming a private (ie. corporate) CA used for both ends here.

Comment: @ewok see `man pkcs12` -- particularly `-cacerts` in conjunction with `-out`. That said, Bruno's warning applies -- the client and server certificates may or may not be signed by the same CA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Server address and port are specified as part of the socket address in line 9, specified as the parameter to `connect`.
2. Generally, you've acquired the CA certificate via some out-of-band method, then saved it locally.  Linux systems generally have a bundle of certificates for well-known, trusted CAs available under `/etc/ssl/certs` or similar.

Comment: the code is being run on Windows.  any idea where it would be stored there?  would it be retrievable through security exceptions saved in firefox?

Comment: You can export the CA certificates from Firefox, sure, if you know which CA signed the server's certificate.  Use PEM format for use with the `ssl` library (see http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html#certificates).  But if the server was not signed by one of those CAs, you will want to ask the organization that runs the server about getting a certificate.