# Sending mail with python SMTP to outlook/microsoft gives SMTPAuthenticationError: Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: python, email, outlook, smtp

I have a problem described and solved for gmail in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852128/smtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-mail-using-gmail-and-python). I have read through several posts dealing with similar issues ([Sending mail from Python using SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505/sending-mail-from-python-using-smtp), [Sending email from Python using STARTTLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857698/sending-email-from-python-using-starttls), [smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602682/smtplib-smtpauthenticationerror-535-5-7-3-authentication-unsuccessful)) and also some external support on Microsoft (eg. [send email using Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fhow-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4) but in none I was able to figure out how to fix my error.

My code is this:

```py
import getpass
import smtplib

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.starttls()

a = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
mailserver.login('name@domain.com', a)
```

and connection is established (ie. I get `250` for `.ehlo` and `220` for `.starttls`) but the last step gives me:

```py
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [LO4P123CA0352.GBRP123.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError) says:

> SMTP authentication went wrong. Most probably the server didn’t accept the username/password combination provided.

I am sure that my password and username are correct (triple checked that). Also, I looked to my account and in the Microsoft account it shows that POP and IMAP are allowed and it gives me:

```
Server name: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
Encryption method: STARTTLS
```

so everything should be ok. I have also tried port 25 which gives the same error. Where is the problem? How can I make it work for Outlook/Microsoft 365? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Some servers require you to do `ehlo` again after `starttls`

Comment: I added one more `mailserver.ehlo()` after `mailserver.starttls()` but still the same error.