# Get Python to verify SSL certificates in corporate network

Tags: python-3.x, ssl-certificate, jira-rest-api, hp-alm

I am struggling to get `Python` verify the `SSL` certificates that are available inside my corporate network. My `Python` scripts are failing with error `"CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"` when I try to connect to `ALM` and `JIRA`.

Can someone help to get my `Python` verify the certificates that I have with me?

Thanks
Shanto

Comment: You need to provide more details than just the description!

Comment: I have an application hosted in my corporate network which is not accessible from outside world. This has an SSL certificate. When i connect to this site through Python, the SSL verification is failing. I have the web applications SSL certificate with me. But how can i get Python to verify that SSL certificate?

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087227/validate-ssl-certificates-with-python?rq=1