# Is it possible to verify the SSL or TLS certificate of links that are posted?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

## Some information that may help

So, my automatic moderation bot on my Discord server is created in Python with discord.py, I have set some restrictions on the bot to only allow links immediately that have an exception. When a link is not exempt from the filter and a user posts the link, the bot will request for a human to review to approve the link if:

- The link is verified with an SSL or TLS certificate,
- The link extension is a trustworthy one such as **.com**, **.net**, or **.org** if it is a domain name. If it is a direct IP address, the bot will verify if the IP range is trustworthy.
- FTP server links and links with self-signed SSL or TLS certificates must be exempted from the filter by a staff member in advance.

The link will automatically be denied if it meets the following:

- The link extension is **.onion**,
- Uses an insecure method of connection such as HTTP,
- The link has been previously marked for phishing, malicious intent, inappropriate content, or scams.
- The SSL or TLS certificate is:

  - invalid,
  - misconfigured,
  - uses an insecure cipher suite or encryption algorithm,
  - the integrity or genuineness failed to be verified.

---

## My question

So my question is, would it be possible to make the bot verify the SSL or TLS certificate associated with the link, following the above standards automatically? I want to add this to the filter to prevent users from posting untrustworthy links that may impersonate a genuine website, or spam.

I just require a response that states whether this is possible, any additional information would be unnecessary.

Comment: Definitely possible.  Some relevant discussion is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087227/validate-ssl-certificates-with-python

Comment: For testing you can use https://badssl.com/